# SQL - Query Multiple Dissimilar Tables (not UNION)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Language**: T-SQL
**Server**: SQL Server 2008 R2 - SQL Server 2014

I have what, based on searching here an elsewhere, appears to either be a unique problem or I can't properly verbalize what I'm trying to accomplish. I'd like to query across multiple **dissimilar** tables that have dissimilar field structures and JOIN them to a single other table. We have a table of ASSETS `tb_assets` and a table of LICENSES `tb_licenses`. I'd like to query across both of these and JOIN them to the table of VENDORS `tb_vendors`.

Like this:

```
----------------------                       ---------------------------
|      TB_ASSETS     |                       |    TB_LICENSES          |
----------------------                       ---------------------------
| f_assetvendor      | <~~~             ~~~> | f_licensevendor         |
| f_assettag         |    |             |    | f_licensename           |
| f_assetname        |    |             |    | f_licenseexpirationdate |
|                    |    |             |    | f_licensequantity       |
----------------------    |             |    ---------------------------
                          |             |
                   ~~~~~~~~             ~~~~~~~~~~
                   |    ----------------------   |
                   |    |     TB_VENDORS     |   | 
                   |    ----------------------   | 
                   ~~>  | f_vendorGUID       | <~~
                        | f_vendorname       |
                        ----------------------
```

For a short example, I want to search for a vendor name (`f_vendorname`) of Amazon, I'd like to query against `tb_assets` as well as against `tb_licenses`. The query I tried below errors with `Invalid column name 'f_assetvendor'`, so I'm doing something wrong.

```
SELECT 
    f_assetvendor AS 'AssetVendor', f_licensevendor as 'LicenseVendor'
FROM 
    tb_assets, tb_licenses
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_vendors assven ON assven.f_vendorGUID = f_assetvendor
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_vendors licven ON licven.f_vendorGUID = f_licensevendor
WHERE 
    f_vendorname LIKE '%Amazon%'
```

Regarding my title stating "not UNION", I can't use a UNION here because with UNION column names for the final result set are taken from the first query, the columns must have the same data types, and both tables must have the same number of columns.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely NOT** mix the two styles! Stick to the proper ANSI JOIN - always.

Comment: @marc_s, I can't JOIN the top two tables together since they have no columns on which to JOIN to each other.

Comment: @Beems you can use CROSS JOIN

Comment: can each table `tb_assets, tb_licenses` have multiple rows per `f_vendorGUID`?  if so are you just duplicating the data?

Comment: @Beems: if you have no common column, then it's a `CROSS JOIN` - and there you have your **proper ANSI JOIN** to use ....

Comment: Sample data showing initial table sets and the desired results would be very useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go;

```
SELECT
    v.f_vendorGUID, 
    v.f_vendorname,
    a.f_assetvendor AssetVendor,
    l.f_licensevendor LicenseVendor
FROM 
    TB_VENDORS v
JOIN 
    TB_ASSETS a ON v.f_vendorGUID = a.f_assetvendor
JOIN 
    TB_LICENSES l ON v.vendorGUID = l.f_licensevendor
WHERE 
    v.vendorname LIKE '%Amazon%'
```

You can use the TB_VENDORS as the main table and join the other two tables to it, in this instance (inner join) there's no particular order they should be in. You've shown in your diagram that there's a join between these tables. If you have the chance of missing data in either TB_ASSETS or TB_LICENCES, use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Please get out of the habit of that old style join you've used in your FROM statement, it's a really old way of doing it.

Comment: Sorry @Rich, I was wrong before. This is joining the results from the Assets and Licenses tables, which is what I was needing to avoid. For example, If I have one license and one asset matching the vendor of Amazon, it returns a single row and joins those. If i have two Assets and one License I get two rows.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way of doing what you want. Please provide some sample data for the tables and the output that you're after. I'll then revise my answer to give you the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said no to a union statement but I think this gives you what you need unless I am misunderstanding your query.

```
Select  [t].[Vendor]
      , [t].[VendorType]
From    ( Select    [f_assetvendor] As 'Vendor'
                  , 'Asset' As 'VendorType'
          From      [tb_assets]
                    Left Join [tb_vendors] [assven]
                        On [assven].[f_vendorGUID] = [f_assetvendor]
          Union All
          Select    [f_licensevendor] As 'Vendor'
                  , 'License' As 'VendorType'
          From      [tb_licenses]
                    Left Join [tb_vendors] [licven]
                        On [licven].[f_vendorGUID] = [f_licensevendor]
        ) [t]
Where [t].[Vendor] Like '%Amazon%';
```

However you get there, you will need to make your tables similar enough to report together.